# TypeORM import of Relation fails

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, es6-modules

I am using typeorm in a nodejs project with esm. I need to use the Relation wrapper to avoid circular dependencies.

I get this error when i try to use the relation wrapper:

```
import { Column, Entity, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Relation } from 'typeorm';
                                                           ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'typeorm' does not provide an export named 'Relation'
```

The code file:

```js
import { Column, Entity, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Relation } from 'typeorm';
import { Vehicle } from './vehicle';

@Entity({ name: 'vehicle_default_values' })
export class VehicleDefaultValues {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ unsigned: true })
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'int', unsigned: true, unique: true })
    model: number;

    @Column({ type: 'float', default: 550 })
    maxFuel: number;

    @Column({ type: 'boolean', default: false })
    isElectric: boolean;

    @Column({ type: 'float', default: 0.008 })
    fuelConsumption: number;

    @Column({ type: 'mediumint', unsigned: true, default: 200 })
    maxSpeed: number;

    @Column({ type: 'mediumint', unsigned: true, default: 50 })
    trunkVolume: number;

    @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
    vehicleExtras: string;

    @OneToOne(() => Vehicle, (vehicle) => vehicle.vehicleDefaultValues)
    vehicle: Relation<Vehicle>;
}
```

Used version of typeorm: 0.3.7

Comment: Ok it does not work with swc but works with tsc...

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because the types are not included when converting the file to javascript. The imports `Column`, `Entity`, `OneToOne`, `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` are all functions, while the import `Relation` is a type.

With [typescript 3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) or newer you can explicitly tell that you are importing types like this:

```
import { Column, Entity, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import type { Relation } from 'typeorm';
```

or with [typescript 4.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-modifiers-on-import-names) or newer you can do the same like this:

```
import { Column, Entity, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, type Relation } from 'typeorm';
```

Comment: This actually worked for me, saved me a lot , thanks.